# Problem with subdomains using .htaccess to redirect non-www URLs to www (301)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I redirected non-www request to www through .htaccess Rewrite Rule.

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
>
> RewriteRule (.*) www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

But now I am having problems with subdomains. When I am accessing `touch.111.com` then the above rule redirects to `touch.www.111.com` (which is not accessible), and the website breaks on touch devices.

Please advise me on how to fix the above problem.

Answer (score 4):

You must be specific if you want to redirect only `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` and retain sub-domains (such as `touch.domain.com`) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've already tried your solution and in that case application redirected like: www.touch.domain.com :)

Anyway I have now changed to serve all request without www which is also safe for SEO perspective.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic solution that can work for any domain name:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

see http://www.htaccessredirected.com/force-redirecting-non-www-to-www-htaccess.htm

Comment: Best solution out there.

Comment: What if site is under SSL?

Answer (score 0):

```
# For sites running on a port other than 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]

# And for a site running on port 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html
```